# fixed dropdown won't float to the right

Tags: html, css

I decided that my right floated dropdown-menu should be fixed. However, as soon as I position it to be fixed, it jumps to the left side. How can I fix this? I know I could use padding-left to move it. But I hope their is a more appropriate way to do this.

```css
/*body*/
html, body {
 font-size: 100%;
 height: 100%
}


/*Header*/

.dropdown img {
 height: 2.5em;
 width: 3.5em;
}

.dropdown-menu {  
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}


.header {
 background:url(/img/sri.jpg) no-repeat center center;
 background-size: cover;
 background-attachment: fixed;
 position: relative;
 box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1000px rgba(125, 132, 145, 0.6);
 min-height: 100%
}


.header ul li a {
 color: #fff;
}

.header .logo {
 float: left;
 margin-top: 0.42em;
}


.header .dropdown {
 float: right;
 margin-top: 0.42em;
 position: fixed;
}

.dropdown ul {
 top: 2em;
 left:-8em;
 width: auto;
}

.header .logo p {
 font-size: 1em;
 color: black;
 font-family: 'Permanent Marker', cursive;
 font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="logo"><p>blablabla</p></div>
   <div class="dropdown">
    <img src="img/menuwhite.jpg">
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
     <li><a href="#">Find me on Linkedin</a><li>
     <li><a href="#">Send me an email</a></li>
     <li><a href="#" download="Resume">Download my resume</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div> 
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: dont use position:fixed , you can use position:absolute

Answer (score 2):

Try `right: 0;`:

```
.header .dropdown {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 0.42em;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
}
```

That should do it. (`float: right;` would become irrelevant)

Comment: Did the trick! Thanks. Should I then use padding-right if I want it to move a bit away from the right side of the screen?

Comment: **padding-right** would do it, and **right: 10px;** would do it too, just as Taniya said below...

Comment: Does this solve your problem? Will you accept the answer?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to make the position of the menu fixed then no need to make it float right. Just put right value as per your requirement.

```
.header .dropdown {
  /*float: right;*/
  margin-top: 0.42em;
  position: fixed;
  right: 10px; //put the value you need
}
```